# What is the meaning of Coherence by Whitehead?

Tags: philosophy-of-logic, whitehead

I am just started reading the book Process and Reality. On page 5, He talked about what is the accentual thing we have to keep in mind while building a speculative philosophy.

Pints are

- Rational side.

  - Coherent
  - logic
- Empirical side.

  - applicable
  - adequate

I am quoting from the book on page 5.

[image]

What is he saying?

Comment: It does not seem [Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency).

Comment: Whitehead is declaring that he subscribes to what is now called [inferentialism (or conceptual role semantics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferential_role_semantics) about the meaning of concepts "that identifies the meaning of an expression with its relationship to other expressions (typically its inferential relations with other expressions)". In other words, what defines a concept in his system is its "coherence" with the rest of the system. More commonly, "coherence" refers to mutual *justification* of beliefs rather than to mutual *definition* of concepts.

Comment: Seems like a good way to build a universe.